# Android: How to replicate this screenshot?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

[image: Screesshot]

Can someone shine some light on which controls are being used here? 
The top are tabs that only change the left part of the screen, and the left part I don't know how to may those squares? 
Can anyone help?

Comment: GridLayout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: can you explain exactly what part you need?

Comment: I don't know how to make the squares, I've been trying with gridlayout, and with tablelayout but I don't know how to make those perfect squares, and also have the screen divided by two layouts like in the picture